# Skip bytes in ByteArray Java

Tags: java, png, arrays, skip

My app reads a png-like file (in byte) and stores bytes into a byteArray.
This is the method I use :

```
public static byte[] read(File file) throws IOException {

        byte []buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream ios = null;
        try {
            ios = new FileInputStream(file);
            if ( ios.read(buffer) == -1 ) {
                throw new IOException("EOF reached while trying to read the whole file");
            }        
        } finally { 
            try {
                 if ( ios != null ) 
                      ios.close();
            } catch ( IOException e) {
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

After that, I want to extract patterns of that byteArray.
It follows the pattern of png file : 
4 bytes length + 4 bytes types + data (optional) + CRC and repeats that scheme.

I want to do something like a do while : reading the length + type. If I'm not interested of the type, I want to skip that chunk.
But I'm struggling because I can't find any *skip method* for byteArray[].

Does anyone have an idea of how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use ByteArrayInputStream http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html? there is skip method

Comment: I saw this Class earlier. But I don't know how to use it. Do I have to replace my FileInputStream to my ByteArrayInputStream ?

Comment: If there is nothing crucial for you in FileInputStream you can just replace it, both of them has the same superclass. Is that enough example for you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bytearrayinputstream_skip.htm?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the help. I'm working on it. Will give you a feedback ! ;)

Comment: I finally manage to make it work way faster. (before : 7 sec, now : 0,4 seconds) 
I've only one little question now : 
I make a do while with this condition : if chunk is end_chunk then it's over.
Things work great but if it's a corrupted file (with no end), that will loop and don't stop since my file has no end chunk. How can I surpass that ?

Many thanks to you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295221/java-net-url-read-stream-to-byte  maybe this  will help you :) I'm glad that I've helped you so far :)

Comment: I'm in a do {....... switch{....} }while.
How can I get out of my do while if I am in a switch case ?

Comment: You can't get out of switch because nothing fits ?

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the answer. I spoke too fast.
My while condition was bad. Now everything's working! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the array with a while and you need to skip to the next iteration on a given condition you can use the label continue to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

The syntax is as follows:

```
do {
    if (condition) {
        continue;
    }
    // more code here that will only run if the condition is false
} while(whatever you use to iterate over your array);
```

Comment: That's my idea. But I don't know how to fill the white arguments.
For the moment I've made a "for loop" that increments bytes per bytes and searching for the 4-bytes TYPE. But this loop is so slow : 7 seconds for a 20Mb file. (I have 250Mb file to read)